# callback in multiparty form parsing is not executed, seems (express 3)

Tags: node.js, express

I am learning to handle file upload in express 3.
module.exports.upload is my route handler for POST request to '/image/upload' :

```
var multiparty = require('multiparty');
module.exports.uploadPage = function (req, res) {
    res.render('image/image', {file_content: null });
}
module.exports.upload = function (req, res) {
    var form = new multiparty.Form();
    form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files){
        console.log('inside form parsing call back');
        res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/plain'});
        res.end('received upload:\n\n');
    });
    if(req.method == 'GET') res.render('image/image');
}
```

this is my form:

```
<form action="/image/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <input type="file" name="thumbnail" multiple="multiple" />
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

the **console.log('inside form parsing call back');** is never executed since nothing is logged in terminal. I am using dev setting, the POST request log is even not logged to console.

Btw, I compared my code with example [here](https://github.com/superjoe30/node-multiparty/blob/master/examples/upload.js). I beleive I am doing it right, but I can be wrong.

The callback seems not to be executed in this situation. Where went wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Let me answer my question. The above code is good, but the reason it doesn't work is because I added

```
app.use(express.multipart());
```

in app.js

then add

```
var multiparty = require('multiparty');
```

again in the controller, which is image.js

This may not be helpful to you, but the take away is that only load(require(...)) multiparty where it needs to process forms. Don't use app.use, use require as this document suggests:

[multiparty on github](https://github.com/superjoe30/node-multiparty/)